# Save more than one NSData files to documents folder in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsdata

I want to save multiple images to my documents path folder. My web service returns more than one image url path and i want to save each image to my documents folder.This process working successfully, but my view FREEZES at this time(converting image url to NSData).I am using following code.How to avoid this issue?

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[usersArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"message"]]];
NSString *localImgpath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",imageName, @"png"]];
[data writeToFile:localImgpath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You're not happy with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to process that in a background thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[usersArray    objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"message"]]];
    NSString *localImgpath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",imageName, @"png"]];
    [data writeToFile:localImgpath atomically:YES];
});
```